# Python module install error when I tried to pip numpy

Tags: python

When I install `numpy` lib using `python -m pip install numpy==1.18.1` command, I got the following errors.

```
ramirami-pc:anomalydetector sclee01$ python -m pip install numpy==1.18.1
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Collecting numpy==1.18.1
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [705 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/tools/cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.14')
      /private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/tools/cythonize.py:77: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
      numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in has not changed
      numpy/random/_philox.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_bit_generator.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in has not changed
      numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx has not changed
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx
      numpy/random/mtrand.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_generator.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx has not changed
      numpy/random/_common.pyx has not changed
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      .........
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
      
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/npymath
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath
      compile options: '-Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
      In file included from numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c:9:
      numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src:490:21: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'npy_longdouble *' (aka 'double *') to parameter of type 'long double *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          return modfl(x, iptr);
                          ^~~~
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/include/math.h:394:52: note: passing argument to parameter here
      extern long double modfl(long double, long double *);
                                                         ^
      1 warning generated.
      ar: adding 4 object files to build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/libnpymath.a
      ranlib:@ build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/libnpymath.a
      building 'npysort' library
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
      
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort
      compile options: '-Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      22 warnings generated.
      ar: adding 7 object files to build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/libnpysort.a
      ranlib:@ build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/libnpysort.a
      running build_ext
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler using new_build_ext
      building 'numpy.core._multiarray_tests' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
      
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/common
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.c
      In file included from numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c.src:7:
      In file included from numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_math.h:643:
      numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src:490:21: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'npy_longdouble *' (aka 'double *') to parameter of type 'long double *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          return modfl(x, iptr);
                          ^~~~
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/include/math.h:394:52: note: passing argument to parameter here
      extern long double modfl(long double, long double *);
                                                         ^
      numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c.src:1923:61: warning: format specifies type 'long double' but the argument has type 'npy_longdouble' (aka 'double') [-Wformat]
              PyOS_snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%.*Lg", precision, x);
                                               ~~~~~              ^
                                               %.*g
      2 warnings generated.
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38 -lnpymath -o build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-38-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
      building 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
      
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/multiarray
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/umath
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/numpy
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/numpy/_build_utils
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/numpy/_build_utils/src
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      extra options: '-faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/common.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/conversion_utils.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.c
      clangclang: : error: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitlythe clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/hashdescr.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime_strings.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/refcount.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/temp_elide.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/vdot.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/numpyos.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/npy_longdouble.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: /private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-install-sh2vo79x/numpy_2f275be08abf460d9f7ebbc831c5ddb7/numpy/_build_utils/src/apple_sgemv_fix.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      Running from numpy source directory.
      /private/var/folders/9x/grsv4dws25j7wc9f16mt6fzx7nz37c/T/pip-build-env-vcfnfhxr/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-38/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

I don't know why this errors happened.
Note that I should install 1.18.1 numpy for the project.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your python version? you can check using `python --version`

Comment: My python version is 3.8.

Comment: And also I know that 3.8 python version is compatible with those numpy version. So I don't know why it throw error.

Comment: Tried upating `pip`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command (worked for me):

`python -m pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.18.1`

Answer (score -1):

The first solution to remove this error is to first upgrade the pip command. After upgrading try to install the NumPy version using the pip command. But make sure to check the version of the python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try updating pip: `pip install --upgrade pip` on command line